# Django taking too long to initialize middleware

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm investigating some slow requests in our server using Datadog frame graphs. I found an interesting thing: this long delay to initialize/call the Django middleware stack.

Any idea of what might be causing this issue/delay?

[image: django_request_framegraph]

Versions:
python=3.10, Django=3.2.18, djangorestframework=3.12.4, drf-jwt=1.19.1

I'm also using remote authentication, but just the first time the django makes the remote request, subsequent requests look in our database. `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication` is also being used.
Moreover, I'm using persistent connection with Postgres 13

Comment: Could you specify Python and Django version?

Comment: @PTomasz added it to description